# Game of Drones - Zap it!

Tags: mathematics, strategy, pursuit-evasion

Your programmable drone is pitted against another drone in a rectangular 3D arena measuring 40 meters long, 40 meters wide and 20 meters high. You have equipped your drone with a laser gun that will take your opponent down as soon as it is within 1 meter reach. This laser makes your drone slightly slower (9.70 m/s maximum speed) compared to your opponent's drone which lacks any weapons and which can reach 10.00 m/s. Both drones are equipped with cameras and accurate accelerometers. All this information is available to on-board processors which control the drone movements and which for all practical purposes can be assumed to be fast enough to avoid any measurable latency in the drone's responses to new information. Apart from the laser action, neither drone can influence the movements of the other (air currents and other aerodynamic interactions can be assumed to be insignificant), and both drones are light enough for gravity to be negligible.

Your opponent is allowed to select a starting corner, and your drone is placed in the opposing corner, and subsequently both drones are released at the same time. To make things a bit more challenging for you, prior to the drone battle your opponent is allowed a detailed inspection of the program that controls the movements of your drone.

Can you device a strategy that guarantees your drone takes down the opponent's drone?

Comment: Wouldn't always flying directly towards your target work?  You'd get within a meter eventually.

Comment: If the target moves in a circle and the attack drone always aims directly at it, it would not be able to catch up because it is slower.

Comment: @FlorianF How big of a circle and how far behind do you need to be?  You don't have to catch it, just get within a metre.

Comment: It looks a radius of 5 would be large enough.  You need sqrt(radius^2-(radius*.97)^2)>1 in the long term.  This is for a stupid drone who aims straight at the target.

Comment: @FlorianF: That's only accurate if you aim directly where the defending drone _was_.  If you aim for where the defending drone _is_, then the "radius" of your circle is smaller.  However, if his circle is big enough, the radius difference may not be enough to catch up, I'd have to do the math.

Comment: Biggest perfect circle the target can fly in has a radius of 22.360679775.  Attack bot can match the angular speed with a radius of 21.6450722605, which is less than a meter apart.  I think that's evidence enough that it would catch up eventually, though I'm fuzzy on how to prove it.

Comment: I made a simulation.  Attacker starts at (0,0), target flies around a circle of radius 4.4.  The attack drone never arrives within 1 unit of the target.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The attack drone should fly to a virtual target that is always at 29/30 of the way from the center of the room to the target drone.  That point moves 3.3% slower than the target drone.

Since the attack drone flies only 3% slower than the target drone, it can reach that virtual target in a finite time regardless how the target drone moves.

Since the maximum distance from the center to any place of the room is a convenient 30 meters, the distance between the virtual target and the real target is never more than 1 meter.  So when the attack drone reaches the virtual target, the real target is in range.

And Zap!

Comment: I like it! Short, crisp, and obvious.  Well done!

Answer (score 0):

You drone should just takeoff and then shoot immediately.

The person who sold you a "1 meter reach" laser clearly doesn't understand how light works.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you can equally view the drone as using a lightsaber or something instead. Unless the question is asking for you to intentionally think outside the box, or there is in fact no good answer, there is no need to provide such answers.

Comment: Lasers diffuse with distance and interactions with the atmosphere.  It could be that the laser is only optimally functional within 1 metre and that outside that range it diffuses too much to be effective.

Comment: The "laser" is one of these translucent tubes with leds inside that you find in toy shops.  I am pretty sure you can down a drone with that.