# Decipher the crazy emails!

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

I've been trying to write some emails to my friends, but something is going horribly wrong! It's as though the [devil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13196/game-against-the-devil) himself has hold of me: everything I type comes out as gibberish! The first email I wrote looked like this:

```
\ehsy dhsll er fo yhid errkrnf\/ \lry'd ho domrehrtr inyrtrdyinh\2
```

The second one came out like this:

```
U fauk ti cinoregebd tiyr kast enauk, Wgt> Nt qyestuib us wgt, Kiij deeokt,
```

The third one was worst of all!

```
\drr tiy ib \ygytdfst\2 \giorgykkt er;kk skk vr ygrtr ygud yunr,
```

Can you help me to decipher these emails so that my friends don't think I'm a raving lunatic? (Well, I *am* a raving lunatic, but I wasn't trying to type gibberish just now!)

Comment: This puzzle suffers from localization issues.  On my keyboard the last message would have been `<drr tiy ib <ygytdfst<2 <giorgykkt erækk skk vr ygrtr ygud yunr,`

Comment: So now we know you aren't a follower of Dvorak....interesting..

Comment: @Taemyr You have an "æ" on your keyboard? Are you Norwegian by any chance?

Comment: More seriously, I realised this localisation thing might be a problem, but wasn't sure how to resolve it without giving away the solution! I couldn't have said "I'm using a UK-style QWERTY keyboard". Maybe I could have a spoilertagged "Hint: I'm in the UK." Suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**First message:**

```
   What shall we do this weekend? Let's go somewhere interesting!
```

*How to get it:* move left-hand keys one place to the left and leave right-hand keys as they are to decrypt

**Second message:**

```
 I fail to comprehend your last email. Why, my question is why. look deeply.
```

*How to get it:* move right-hand keys one place to the right and leave left-hand keys as they are to decrypt

**Third message:**

```
 See you on Thursday! Hopefully we'll all be there this time.
```

*How to get it:* move left-hand keys one place to the left and right-hand keys one place to the right to decrypt

Comment: First message: What shall we do this weekend? Let's go somewhere interesting!

Comment: yes that's it. I had it all except for the first What... dunno how can you reach \ trying to get w. I edit my answer with it ok? :)

Comment: The '\' is one key to the right of the shift key

Comment: Third message: See you on Thursday! Hopefully we'll all be there this time.

Comment: Second message should be: Why, instead of Why>

Comment: Ohhh I see now why!!! It's because I'm from spain and the spanish keyboard is diferrent than the english so, that's why you have there the \ while I have it on the left side of the number '1'  key. Didn't thought about that until now! I update the answer then :)

Comment: Nice job! You got all the messages right, but the explanation in your first paragraph looks a bit odd. PS: welcome to Puzzling.SE :-)

Comment: @randal'thor yes, i didn't know how to explian it really... but I 've just edited it and I think  it's more clear now :) Thank you! I saw this one and wanted to try so I made the account ^^

Comment: Your explanation (i.e. move right-hand keys one place to the right and leave left-hand keys as they are to decrypt) only works for the second message. The first and third have different algorithms, although along the same lines.

Comment: well initially i put it only for the second one but then thought it would work for all. But its true. I'll edit it now

Comment: Almost right, except that it's left-hand keys one place to the _left_ and right-hand keys one place to the right to decrypt (the other way round to encrypt, of course).

Comment: @randal'thor again I was thinking  on encrypt and not to decrypt hehe thank you!!! I really enjoyed this puzzle!  and your lunatic part :P